# Como bloquear e desobrir uma range IPs de uma cidade/estato no .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache

queria bloquear temporariamente alguns estados do Brasil para não acessarem o meu site, como eu posso fazer isso através do htaccess.

Na verdade, o mais difícil é descobrir essa range de IPs de cada estado ou cidade?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Até onde sei a faixa de IP é pro Brasil todo, não tendo divisões específicas por estado. O que penso ser possível pra isso é cruzar informações do IP em algum serviço de geolocalização e bloquear dinamicamente.

Comment: Procure por Geolocalização IP, existem vários sites que verificam sua localização e você pode realizar testes.